# React native fetch() causing unknown error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\root\react-native\ReactAndroid\hermes-engine.cxx\Release

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, api, fetch-api

I have made a simple REST API, and I have a react native application where I am trying to call the API with fetch. The server is running on the same computer as the react native application, in my fetch call I used 'fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/Users)' which from what I know is the correct way to call it. When I run my react-native application to test if the connection works, I get the following error:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\root\react-native\ReactAndroid\hermes-engine.cxx\Release\21w5t5f5\x86_64\lib\InternalBytecode\InternalBytecode.js'
at Object.openSync (node:fs:584:3)
at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:452:35)
at getCodeFrame (C:\Users\brayd\projects\startscreentest\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1004:18)
at Server._symbolicate (C:\Users\brayd\projects\startscreentest\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1073:22)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Server._processRequest (C:\Users\brayd\projects\startscreentest\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:437:7) {
errno: -4058,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'C:\root\react-native\ReactAndroid\hermes-engine.cxx\Release\21w5t5f5\x86_64\lib\InternalBytecode\InternalBytecode.js'

Has anyone got this error before and know of a a solution? Would really appreciate some help with this, I have been tried almost everything I can think of and at this point I am lost as to what I should do.

I have never seen this error before, I have looked online to see if anyone has posted a solution and found nothing, I have no idea how to solve this error, I have been debugging for hours, and have tried countless things including changing the fetch url, making a new application, etc. I know the api works because I have tested all the routes with curl, I know the fetch statements work because I created a js project and tested the fetch statements. For some reason, its just not working on my react-native application, its either giving me the above error, or if I change the url  to something else like 'fetch('http://localhost:3000/Users)' it just gives me 'network connection error'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a  wamp or nginx server on your computer. Then your API project starts on a server. After that, you can access your pc IP address. Actually, your react native simulator doesn't work on your pc. So you can't access the directly pc IP address.

Comment: before I run the fetch command I already have the api running on my localhost server, so I don't think the issue is with the API not running

Comment: Your mobile and your pc localhosts different. You can not access your pc localhost from phone or phone similator.

Comment: But both device use same network. İf you have a ngnix or apche server you can access your ip adress over 80 port.